# SPSS Modeler, Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, spss-modeler

can someone explain to me how to connect SPSS Modeler to Hadoop ?

From what I've read, the scheme should be

```
SPSS Modeler Client -> SPSS Modeler Server -> SPSS Analytic Server -> Hadoop.
```

Can I connect them without using SPSS Modeler Server, so the scheme would be:

```
SPSS Modeler Client-> SPSS Analytic Server-> Hadoop/HDFS ?
```

Please help me and thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

No - creating a connection to the SPSS Analytic Server requires that you first connect to an SPSS Modeler Server instance.

I don't know if there is a technical rationale for this requirement, but if you are storing your data in Hadoop, it is probably fair to assume that you have more data that one can reasonably expect to process on a regular desktop or laptop computer.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can connect directly to your Analytic Server instance from Modeler Client if they are compatible versions.  So, for example, the latest version of Modeler Client is 18.1.1, which will connect just fine to Analytic Server 3.1.1 directly.  However, if you had AS 3.1 installed, Modeler Client 18.1.1 would not successfully be able to pull data directly (although it could connect, you would get an ASL error when you tried to read or write data).